# Tor and Teamspeak 3 on Ubuntu

Tags: configuration

**Context :**

OS : Ubuntu 13.10

Software to "torify"  : Teamspeak 3 (download [here](http://dl.4players.de/ts/releases/3.0.14/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_x86-3.0.14.run))

---

**Issue :**

I am trying to run teamspeak 3 thanks to proxychains and Tor on ubuntu, but I don't understand why it isn't forwarded correctly. I manage to run the software, however connection details underlined by Teamspeak 3 are not those expected (of Tor), but mine.

Please note that the proxychains forward I set up is working fine on browsers (firefox/chromium), and even Teamspeak 2 (that was installed thanks to the official repository).

I am wondering where the issue is coming from, and how could I fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I think teamspeak use UDP (UDP for teamspeak 3 but teamspeak 2 use TCP) and is not supported for using through socks. look this post: http://forum.teamspeak.com/showthread.php/81895-UDP-is-blocked-anyway-to-connect-to-TS-server-through-TCP

Sorry, but if someone have a solution I search for.